Azure Data Factory converting my string to a timestamp incorrectly
I have an ADFv2 pipeline in which I'm trying to take a string (or a date) and output it in this format: '2024-07-12T09:29:20.790-07:00' which I thought would be @formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK') this doesn't work however and I end up with "2024-07-12T16:29:20.79Z" Well Workday wants the string in the format of 2024-07-12T09:29:20.790-07:00. Also format of 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffkkk' does not work either.
I've tried converting my date to a string and concat the -07:00 that worked until I replace the "2024-07-12 09:29:20.790-07:00" The space with a T and then I ended up with '2024-07-12T16:29:20.79Z'.  As soon as the string had a T in it ADF converted it to a timestamp even though I wanted it to be a string.
Here is the current conversion attempts this first one with formatDateTime:
@formatDateTime(replace(concat(
    substring(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment, 0, length(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment)),
    if(
        and(
            greaterOrEquals(substring(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment, 0, 10), concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy'),'-03-10')),
            lessOrEquals(substring(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment, 0, 10), concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy'),'-11-03'))
        ),
        '-07:00',
        '-08:00'
    )
), ' ', 'T'), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz')

And this one just has the replace:
@replace(concat(
    substring(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment, 0, length(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment)),
    if(
        and(
            greaterOrEquals(substring(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment, 0, 10), concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy'),'-03-10')),
            lessOrEquals(substring(activity('Create Edition').output.firstRow.StartCreatedMoment, 0, 10), concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy'),'-11-03'))
        ),
        '-07:00',
        '-08:00'
    )
), ' ', 'T')

If you remove the replace the string is exactly how I want it, but I need to replace the ' ' (space) with a 'T'
How do I get ADF to format my date timestamp the way I want it to be?
After becoming super frustrated with my conversion attempts above I started playing around with what I could pass into Workday.  I ended up converting the string to UTC in SQL like this: format(cast((@StartCreatedMoment AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATETIME), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ') Workday accepted this format. I still want to know how to do this in an activity. Add the "-07:00"

You can simply concat the toString results of currentTimestamp() or any dateInput you are having in the dataflow expression.
concat(
    toString(rawDateInput, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    'T',
    toString(rawDateInput, "HH:mm:ss", '-0700'),
    '-07:00'
)

output:

raw json
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "test",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',",
                "     format: 'table') ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(rawDateInput = currentTimestamp()) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 derive(output = concat(",
                "    toString(rawDateInput, \"yyyy-MM-dd\"),",
                "    'T',",
                "    toString(rawDateInput, \"HH:mm:ss\", '-0700'),",
                "    '-07:00'",
                ")) ~> derivedColumn2"
            ]
        }
    }
}


I use ADF all the time and have not used data flows yet, so trying to test this I was unsuccessful, but looks like a solid solution.  My question is specifically trying to get this answer via transformations in the Activity
